# Running bookmarklet from a keyboard shortcut in Opera

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts, opera, bookmarklet

The Opera web browser makes it very easy for users to tie keyboard shortcuts to bookmarks by editing the keyboard.ini file, e.g.

```
F1 = http://google.com/
```

will allow a single keystroke <kbd>F1</kbd> to Google.

I'd like to similarly tie a keyboard shortcut to a **bookmarklet** --- but the following doesn't work:

```
F1 = javascript:alert('Hello, World!')
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this, either using keyboard.ini or through some other means?

(The ultimate goal here is to build a TV-based browser that my grandparents can use.  This means a set of labelled hotkeys on the keyboard that instantly visit sites they like or perform other useful functions.  I'd like the whole package to be contained within Opera.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
F1 = Go to page, "javascript:alert('Hello world')"
```

Would that work?

Comment: From what I remember, it did work in Opera 8; not sure if it still works in 10.50

Answer (score 0):

for chrome: right click on search bar -> edit search engines -> add new engine -> 
three fields 1. name of the engine 2. d 3. javascript: alert("hellow");

final step press Ctr-L + d + Enter
Your bookmark in this case bookmarklet is opened